# What does this if statement check do?

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, boolean

In the following code the programmer puts the name of a function inside an if condition as if to check something before going ahead and registering a callback:

```
#if _DEBUG
    if(glDebugMessageCallback) // He checks this function, presumably it returns true if it exists
{
        cout << "Register OpenGL debug callback " << endl;
        glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS);
        glDebugMessageCallback(openglCallbackFunction, nullptr); // Calls the function here
        GLuint unusedIds = 0;
        glDebugMessageControl(GL_DONT_CARE,
            GL_DONT_CARE,
            GL_DONT_CARE,
            0,
            &unusedIds,
            true);
    }
    else
        cout << "glDebugMessageCallback not available" << endl;  // So if the if condition evaluated to false, the function doesn't exist.
#endif
```

My question is why this way of checking if a function exists?  If a function doesn't exist surely you'll get a compile error telling you that the function doesn't exist, this seems strange to me. I know basically the function address evaluates to bool, and I asked a question before about this and was told that function addresses aren't particularly useful as implicit conversion to bool, and I don't see how.

I should mention also that the function inside the if condition is a MACRO define, defined as:

```
#define glDebugMessageCallback GLEW_GET_FUN(__glewDebugMessageCallback)
```

If it being a define macro makes a difference.

Comment: Its a callable convertible to `bool`, likely to be a function pointer.

Comment: Most OpenGL functions are dynamically loaded at runtime, that's one of the things GLEW does.

Comment: This is a check for existing callback. Callbacks in their nature might or might not exist and this does not necessarily known during compilation time. So only during runtime you may tell if the function can be called. Does that makes sense? Thus if you have implicit address converted to True, it means there is a non-null address in this pointer, which should probably point to a callback function.

Comment: Oh, I see, so the thing inside the if condition is a function pointer? That makes sense. I'm wondering if it needs to be initialised to nullptr for it to work properly then.

Comment: Yes, it has to be initialized with some value to behave properly, maybe nullptr.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, thank you. So in other words it's a check to see if GLEW successfully loaded that function pointer. Weird though, because GLEW loads tons and tons of function pointers for the OpenGL API calls, and this is the first time I've seen it checked for validity. Actually this might be a special case because it relies on the debug layer, and is only available from OpenGL 4.3 onwards.

Comment: I don't specifically know OpenGL, but it might be that `GLEW_GET_FUN()` macro returns a pointer on a function, and as it is a macro can be defined under other conditions to return NULL. So it appears legitimate to test the pointer before using it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

glDebugMessageCallback is either going to be null (0), or the (presumably valid) address of a function that matches the signature required.

The if statement will evaluate to true for any non-null value, and false for a null value. (there may be a compiler warning, but the code will work.)

So, if glDebugMessageCallback was initialized to null, and never set to a function address, the if statement will evaluate to false.  If glDebugMessageCallback was set to the address of a function, the code inside the if block will execute, and the function will be called.

Comment: It's unlikely to be a compiler warning, it's too common an idiom